# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when trying to load a bitmap into imageView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bitmap

I'm trying to load a bitmap into an android imageView.

[image]

but get this `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

how can I avoid this ?

```
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:650)
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:722)
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:790)
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at de.vogella.android.todos.MySimpleArrayAdapter.getView(MySimpleArrayAdapter.java:85)
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2452)
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
10-06 00:11:21.225: E/AndroidRuntime(6825):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
```

Comment: Out of memory occurs usually when you're stuck in an endless loop. It's unlikely to be related to the actual loading of the bitmap. Show us your code where you loop though stuff.

Comment: it falls right after MyListAdapter returns next view, and all works if I comment out the `setImage` line

Comment: read : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: look at : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends how big your bitmap is, Android seems to allocate a little more space than the size of the image when you read the size on your computer. So...

- You could just use a smaller image.
- Google have actually published a guide on avoiding OutOfMemoryErrors [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) which will help a lot, though I had to use a smaller image size as well.
- One method that will almost definitely work is to set [android:largeHeap="true"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap) in your manifest, between your application tags. This will increase your heap size, but may make your app lag a little.

Maybe for you, a combination of these ideas will work.

Comment: It works for me after adding android:largeHeap="true"